# "stty: illegal option" Error whenever i open and close vim

Tags: vim, vi

Whenever I open vim I get this error:

```
stty: illegal option -- --save
usage: stty [-a|-e|-g] [-f file] [options]
```

Then, when I quit I see:

```
stty: illegal option -- 
usage: stty [-a|-e|-g] [-f file] [options]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I've tried both iTerm and terminal. Also, this just randomly started happening it seems. I'm on VIM 7.3. Nothing appears to be wrong with vim, but I just get nasty output. Also, it's nothing in my vimrc file. I removed the file to make sure and I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stty`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty) has nothing to do with Vim. Check (or post) your .vimrc to see if it invokes, somehow, `stty`. Or check your `*rc` files, maybe.

Comment: It's probably `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.cshrc` or similar, where there's an unconditional `stty` command, rather than one that operates only when the shell is being invoked interactively.  That, plus something in the vim startup and shutdown sequences that invoke the shell, will do it.

Comment: I agree with you. The problem is probably in his `*rc` files.

Comment: Pretty sure it's .bash_profile now. Thanks. I removed it temporarily and the error went away. Hmm, digging around it now.

Comment: Ugh, yep, I had some snippet in there to enable `ctrl+s` to save. Removing that fixed it.